# pickling defaultdict with lambda

Tags: python, pickle

I am trying to pickle `defaultdict()`, but couldn't do. What is the correct way?

```
pos = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
neg = defaultdict(lambda: 0)    

countdata = self.getCountdata(pos, neg, totals)
cPickle.dump(countdata, open(CDATA_FILE, 'w'))
```

This gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sentiment_worker.py", line 146, in <module>
    MyDict().gearman_worker.work()
  File "sentiment_worker.py", line 28, in __init__
    self.train()
  File "sentiment_worker.py", line 91, in train
    cPickle.dump(countdata, open(CDATA_FILE, 'w'))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.py", line 70, in _reduce_ex
    raise TypeError, "can't pickle %s objects" % base.__name__
TypeError: can't pickle function objects
```

When I tried dill:

```
import dill
dill.dumps(countdata, open(CDATA_FILE, 'w') )
```

which gives:

```
 File "sentiment_worker.py", line 151, in <module>
    if __name__ == '__main__':
  File "sentiment_worker.py", line 29, in __init__
    self.train()
  File "sentiment_worker.py", line 96, in train
    # cPickle.dump(countdata, open(CDATA_FILE, 'w'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dill/dill.py", line 243, in dumps
    dump(obj, file, protocol, byref, fmode, recurse)#, strictio)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dill/dill.py", line 204, in dump
    pik = Pickler(file, protocol)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dill/dill.py", line 387, in __init__
    StockPickler.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 202, in __init__
    raise ValueError("pickle protocol must be <= %d" % HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
ValueError: pickle protocol must be <= 2
```

What is the correct way to pickle and unpickle the content?

Comment: Is your lambda function just an example, or do you actually just want a `defaultdict(int)`?

Comment: HI, I'm the `dill` author, you are using `dumps`, and not `dump`.  Thus your file handle is being seen as the pickle protocol.

Comment: Have you tried **dump** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `dill`.  You've made a typo… you should have used `dill.dump` instead of `dill.dumps` if you want to `dump` to a file.  If you want to `dump` to a string, use `dumps`.

```
>>> import dill
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> pos = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
>>> neg = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
>>> countdata = (pos,neg)
>>> _countdata = dill.loads(dill.dumps(countdata))
>>> _countdata
(defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x10917f7d0>, {}), defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x10917f8c0>, {}))
>>>
>>> # now dump countdata to a file 
>>> with open('data.pkl', 'wb') as f:
...     dill.dump(countdata, f)
...
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for such clear answer. I want to dump content into pickle file, I tried with `dill.dumps(countdata, open('f1.pickle','w'))` which returns `ValueError: pickle protocol must be <= 2`

Comment: Use `dill.dump` not `dill.dumps`.

Comment: thanks `dill.dump(countdata, open('f1.pickle','w'))` and dd = `dill.load(open('f1.pickle','r'))` solved my issue

Comment: Please refer, next level of issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35628808/eof-issue-while-loading-pickle-file-of-1-4-gb

Comment: Hi @user3666197: In the comments of this issue is the wrong place to solve your question -- a new question.  Please either post as a new question on SO, or submit a ticket for `dill`.  I'll try to answer your question either place.  I'm familiar with `sklearn`, so I'd like to see what you are seeing, and give it a try.